# Quickly navigate to application by typing name of application in XMonad

Tags: window, xmonad, alt-tab

I often have several applications open across several workspaces in XMonad. I'd like to be able to switch between them without hunting; specifically, I'd like to be able to type something that identifies the application window (the window title?) and jump to it. Any creative ideas about how to do that?

Answer (score 9):

You're lucky, what you want already exists: [WindowBringer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Actions-WindowBringer.html)

The procedure is very simple if you have have already a `xmonad.hs` configuration file (as described in linked page):

- Add the correct import at the beginning:

  ```
  import XMonad.Actions.WindowBringer
  ```
- Map keys to functions (to insert near other key mapping):

  ```
  , ((mod1Mask, xK_g     ), gotoMenu)
  , ((mod1Mask, xK_b     ), bringMenu)
  ```

Then when pressing ALT+G that will open `dmenu` (like for launching applications) with running application windows name, and then you can enter the beginning of the name and press enter to jump to it.

The behaviour of ALT+B is the same except that it doesn't focus the windows but instead move it to current workspace.